# ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

Tags: sql, oracle, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I started getting the below `SQL exception` and I don't know what's the root cause for this exception? I am also closing `dbconnection` and `prepared statement` too. Then what's the problem?

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

Below is my code which I am using. Anything wrong in my code?

```
for (Entry<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> entry : GUID_ID_MAPPING.entrySet()) {

    pstatement = db_connection.prepareStatement(PDSLnPConstants.UPSERT_SQL); // create a statement
    pstatement.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
    pstatement.setString(2, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.CGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(3, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.PGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(4, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.SGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(5, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.UID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(6, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.ULOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(7, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.SLOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(8, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.PLOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(9, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.ALOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(10, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.SITE_ID));
    pstatement.executeUpdate();

    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e);
} finally {
    if (pstatement!= null) {
    try {
        pstatement.close();
        pstatement = null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
    }
    if (db_connection!= null) {
    try {
        db_connection.close();
        db_connection = null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the `PreparedStatement` definition should be pulled out of the loop and reused within the loop by calling `clearParameters`:

```
pstatement = db_connection.prepareStatement(PDSLnPConstants.UPSERT_SQL); // create a statement

for (Entry<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> entry : GUID_ID_MAPPING.entrySet()) {

    pstatement.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
    pstatement.setString(2, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.CGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(3, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.PGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(4, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.SGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(5, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.UID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(6, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.ULOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(7, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.SLOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(8, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.PLOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(9, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.ALOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(10, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.SITE_ID));
    pstatement.executeUpdate();

    pstatement.clearParameters();

}
```

You may also want to investigate batch processing (`addBatch`). If you are testing, you may need to wait a bit for the existing "open" cursors to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess I am giving you one way I went around it but anyway a lot of people are going to come across such a problem so I might as well share.

I was using NetBeans 7.3.1 and referring to an Oracle Database on a remote Server so I couldn't edit the Registry Keys and instead I realised I was using **ojdbc14.jar**  and all i needed was **ojdbc6.jar**  in my classpath.

Solution: Used **ojdbc6.jar** instead of **ojdbc14.jar**