# Why "recursive sql" is used in "Dictionary-Managed Tablespaces" in oracle?

Tags: oracle, recursive-query

Oracle documents points out that locally managed tablespace is better than dictionary-managed tablespace in several aspects. one is that recursive sql is used when database allocate free blocks in dictionary-managed tablespace.
Table fet$ has columns (TS#, FILE#, BLOCK#, LENGTH)

Could anyone explain why recursive sql is used for allocation with fet$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be interpreting 'recursive' in the normal programming sense; but [it can have slightly different meanings](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recursive):

> 1. drawing upon itself, referring back.
>      *The **recursive** nature of stories which borrow from each other*
> 2. (*mathematics, not comparable*) of an expression, each term of which is determined by applying a formula to preceding terms
> 3. (*computing, not comparable*) of a program or function that calls itself
> 4. ...

If you interpret it as a recursive function (meaning 3) then it doesn't quite make sense; `fet$` isn't updated repeatedly and an SQL statement doesn't re-execute itself. Here 'recursive' is used more generally (meaning 1, sort of), in the sense that the SQL you run generates another layer of SQL 'under the hood'. Not the same SQL or the same function called by itself, but 'SQL drawing upon SQL', or 'SQL referring back to SQL', if you like.

The [concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/logical.htm#CNCPT1096) - which is where I think you got your question from - says:

> - Avoids using the data dictionary to manage extents
>
> Recursive operations can occur in dictionary-managed tablespaces if
>   consuming or releasing space in an extent results in another operation
>   that consumes or releases space in a data dictionary table or undo
>   segment.

With a table in a dictionary managed tablespace (DMT), when you insert data Oracle has to run SQL statements against the dictionary tables to identify and allocate blocks. You don't normally notice that, but you can see it in trace files and other performance views. SQL statements will be run against `fet$` etc. to manage the space.

The 'recursive' part is that one SQL statement has to execute another (different) SQL statement; and that may in turn have to execute yet another (different again) SQL statement.

With a locally managed tablespace (LMT), block information is held in a bitmap within the tablespace itself. There is no dependence on the dictionary (for this, anyway). That extra layer of SQL is not needed, which saves time - both from the dictionary query itself and from potential concurrency delays, as multiple queries (across the database, for all tablespaces) access the dictionary at the same time. Managing that local block is much simpler and faster.

The concepts guide also says:

> **Note:**   Oracle strongly recommends the use of locally managed tablespaces with Automatic Segment Space Management.

As David says, there's not really any benefit to ever using a dictionary managed tablespaces any more, and unless you've inherited an old database that still uses them - in which case migrating to LMT should be considered - or are just learning for the sake of it, you can pretty much forget about them; anything new should be using LMT really, and references to DMTs are hopefully only of historic significance.

---

I wanted to demonstrate the difference by running a trace on the same `insert` statement against an LMT and a DMT, and showing the extra SQL statements from the trace file in the DMT version; but I can't find a DMT on any database I have access too, going back to 9i, which kind of backs up David's point I suppose. Instead I'll point you to [yet more documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/sqltrace.htm#i18112):

> Sometimes, to execute a SQL statement issued by a user, Oracle
>   Database must issue additional statements. Such statements are called
>   recursive calls or recursive SQL statements. For example, if you
>   insert a row into a table that does not have enough space to hold that
>   row, then Oracle Database makes recursive calls to allocate the space
>   dynamically. Recursive calls are also generated when data dictionary
>   information is not available in the data dictionary cache and must be
>   retrieved from disk.

You can use the tracing tools described in that document to compare for yourself, if you have access to a DMT; or you can search for examples.

You can see recursive SQL referred to elsewhere, [usually in errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12083712/266304); the error isn't directly in the SQL your are executing, but in extra SQL Oracle issues internally in order to fulfil your request. LMTs just remove one instance where they used to be necessary, and in the process can remove a significant bottleneck.

Comment: +1: There's really no call to be using dictionary-managed tablespaces at all any more.

Comment: @AlexPoole I understand that LMT is better than DMT. My point is why DMT use recursive query. I think oracle run recursive query against $fet, but I cannot figure out **what the recursive query is**. Could you explain more about it?  
  Many thanks.

Comment: @englefly - I think you're interpreting 'recursive' as similar to a recursive function, something which calls itself; it's not quite that literal. I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify that.